# Create data structure or workflow this query

Tags: data-structures

Define the data structure and the code to perform the fallowing: you have been approached by a bicycle factory to create a system for a monthly sales report. The factory manufactures 5 type of bicycles. It has a dealer network to sell the bicycles. The factory sells the bicycle to the dealers and not to the customers directly. Each type of bicycle has it own price and bicycles are sold to the dealers when required.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

It would either be a queue or a graph theory problem but could you specify some example so I can pinpoint it exactly?